Unity - Using Native collections over C#'s collections
I have a game that I'm working on in Unity. I'm using marching cubes to create destructible terrain and it's working well and is reasonably fast (<10ms for a very large chunk of destruction in the worst case scenario). However, every 100 or so intersections I get a large GC spike of about 250ms. This isn't really acceptable.
I've seen some suggestions saying that using an object pool is a good way around this but can I avoid GC altogether? Yes, I'm aware that C# is a GC language but if I use native collections I can dispose of them when I'm done and avoid C#'s GC (hopefully).
I'm trying to understand this choice a bit better:
Are there any other considerations / performance concerns with native collections?
Is it even true that Dispose()ing of a native collection actually avoids GC?
If it is true that I can avoid GC by doing this, why do C#'s collections not provide a method for disposal?
Thank you!

GC actually helps you. It helps claim back the memory. Maybe you could see in Profiler what type of objects are instantiated the most? Maybe there could be used singleton pattern? Or maybe you are creating just to many objects of type List or other collection, instead of just emptying/writing to it? Hard to tell without actual code.


GC actually helps you. It helps claim back the memory.

I'm aware of what GC does. Reclaiming memory through proper disposal means that the GC doesn't have to do any work because it's already been disposed of which (at least in my head) will avoid these large GC spikes I'm seeing.

depends whats creating the large garbage colleciton, as a pool for example avoids that, another thing you could look into would be DOTS..  dots handles a LOT of objects far better than standard gameobjects

Please share a [mcve].

If it is true that I can avoid GC by doing this, why do C#'s collections not provide a method for disposal? What would you anticipate the Dispose method doing exactly? The collections mostly have internal arrays storing the data. When you stop referencing the collection, those arrays will be eligible for GC. Dispose, logically, can't do a better job than just ceasing to reference the collection.

If you know already that you created a bunch of garbage you could of course mitigate the spikes and rather "manually" force a GC.Collect right away instead of waiting until the garbage piles up and GC does it automatically itself

Yes, you can use native collections to avoid GC. They operate on unmanaged memory.
But it is good to use an object pool anyway. GC spikes aren't the only reason to do this, object pool also helps to avoid memory fragmentation.
And if you're happy with the overall performance, it is probably better to start with the object pool of C# collections, as programming with native collections might not be as trivial, and performance improvement can be minimal.
In order to get a significant performance boost from native collections you need to write your code in a way so it can be bursted, which is even less trivial.

If it is true that I can avoid GC by doing this, why do C#'s collections not provide a method for disposal?

Because C# collections are managed collections. They are designed to be used with GC. The reason why C# uses GC is memory safety. The reason why Unity uses C# instead of just exposing C++ is probably because they want to keep the barrier to entry as low as possible.
